# List most recent posts and pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm making my own template for my portfolio. This is my first from scratch up theme in Wordpress so bear over with me, if I don't talk the lingo or know what things are called... ;-)

I've made a frontpage where I want to loop through the last posts in category "Featured" and the last pages with parent page "Cases", limited with 5.

I know how to loop through a list of category posts, but how do I combine that with latest pages?

Comment: Two separate loops.  One for the posts in the category, then another for pages.  If you're not familiar with custom loops, there's lots of decent articles: http://www.kristarella.com/2010/02/wordpress-custom-loops/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a loop to get posts that are a child of:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_parent' => 33, // change this to the ID of the page you need
);

$posts = get_posts($args);

if ($posts) {
    foreach ($posts as $post) { 
         setup_postdata($post);
        // Your PHP code here.
    }
}
```

All of the Wordpress post getting functions will return the posts in an array. If you want to "combine" them you can either do an [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and put the posts from the category loop and the page loop in the same array and iterate through them, or you can do multiple foreach or while loops.